# out of range error when trying to read from a file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a program where it reads from a .txt file three variables (last name, UIN, and their GPA). The program compiles but when I try to run it, it gives me an out of range error. Can someone please tell me where this occurs or why this would occur in my program?

```
    #include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"

struct Student{

private:
    string last_name;
    int UIN;
    double GPA;

public: 

    Student(string l_name, int number, double grade): last_name(l_name), UIN(number), GPA(grade){}
    string getlast_name() const{return last_name;}
    int getUIN() const {return UIN;}
    double getGPA() const{return GPA;}

};

istream &operator >>(istream &in, Student &student){
string last_name;
int UIN;
double GPA;
char c1, c2;
in>>last_name>>UIN>>GPA;
student = Student{last_name, UIN, GPA};
return in;
}

ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const Student &student){
return out<<student.getlast_name()<<" "<<student.getUIN()<<" "<<student.getGPA();
}

int main(){
vector<Student>vi;
int i = 0;

ifstream readStudent;
readStudent.open("student.txt");
while (readStudent.good()){
    readStudent>>vi[i];
    ++i;
}

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
cout<<vi[i]<<endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors comes from:

```
vector<Student> vi;    // an empty vector

readStudent>>vi[i];    // oops, try to access out of bounds
```

When the vector has `N` elements the valid indices are `0` through `N - 1`.  When it's empty you can't use `[]` on it at all.

To insert into a vector use the `push_back` member function. Also you should check your stream extractors for success. You can kill two birds with one stone in `main()`:

```
Student temp;

while ( readStudent >> temp )
    vi.push_back(temp);
```

and you don't need `i` at all. You can use `vi.size()` afterwards to find out how many you read.